# CGAffineTransform scale with slider

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UISlider which goes from 0 to 275. I want to use the slider to scale an UIImageView.

When my slider value is 0 my UIImageView should have the original size (scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1).

When my slider value is 275 my UIImageView should scale to 0.85.

Can someone suggest a good formula to calculate the scale value in relationship with slider value?

Something like this

```
let scale = slider.value >= 275 ? 0.85 : 1
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, scaleY: scale)
```

But I have some trouble making the `scale` dynamic based on slider value.

Comment: Is your slider value used for anything else? If not, set its range to be from 1.0 to 0.85 then you can use its value directly as the scale.

Comment: Why does the slider need to go to 275?

Comment: I'm using the slider for another things as well and I need the 275 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a linear scale such as:

```
let scale = 1.0 - slider.value/275.0 * 0.15
```